# How are the payload limits of robot arms on the space station determined?

Tags: iss, robotic-arm, canadarm

I have just been wondering how the payload limits for the arms on the ISS were determined. Any back of the napkin calculations to explain these? In that vein, I could not find any information on the motor specs for these arms. Has anyone come across these?

Comment: When you're in zero G, you don't really have mass limits in the conventional sense. The space shuttle robotic arm, for instance, isn't even able to support its own weight on earth.

Comment: I am aware of that. But just wanted to know how these arms’ payload capacities are determined (experimentally and/or back-of-the-napkin calculations). They do have rated limits, which most likely stem from a torque-inertia relationship but wanted to see if anyone had the information out there.